# Check if array has at least two elements with specific value

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Assume that I have an array with the following values: `0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1`

I am currently looping over my array and replacing 1's with 0's. However I would to break out of this loop if there are 2 1's left in my array. I don't really have much in terms of code but this is a stub of what I've been working on

```
if(//There are more than 2 1s ){
        return true; //carry on looping
    }

    return false; //break the loop
```

I have no idea how to differentiate between the 0's and the 1's and so I am quite confused with how to get this to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a counter temporary variable.

Comment: First count the number of 1s. Do this once only (your logic would have you count once per loop).

Comment: Isn't it better to loop backwards and just skip the first two 1s?

Comment: Bit operators might be useful.

Comment: The task in the title (check if there are at least two 1s in an array) and the task in the content (delete all ones until 2 are left) are two different tasks. Which is the one you would like to be solved?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to start by writing a utility method to test if a given value at a specific position is unique from every subsequent position in the array like,

```
private static boolean testUnique(int[] arr, int i) {
    int t = arr[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == t) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can iterate the array from the left to the right, checking if every value is unique like

```
public static boolean hasDuplicate(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!testUnique(arr, i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using your array,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    System.out.println(hasDuplicate(arr));
}
```

That is `false`. Alternatively, you might find it easier if you first sort your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] testDuplicatesofOne(int[] arr)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
    {
        count+=(arr[i]>0?1:0);
    }

    if(count>=2)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length-1;j++)
    {
        if(count>2) 
        {
            if(arr[j]==1)
            {
                arr[j]=0;
                count--;
            }
        }else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Hi Lukasz try this, Sorry if I have not understood your requirement properly.